# Incorrect syntax near 'unsigned' en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy intentando crear una simple tabla y no puedo:

```
CREATE TABLE departamento (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Alguien sabe cuál es el problema? por mas sencillo que parezca no lo encuentro, gracias

Comment: ¿Por qué le pones 'unsigned'?

Comment: UNSIGNED no es soportado por SQL Server

Comment: creo que es verdad que no soporta unsigned y de igual forma me doy cuenta que no es necesario. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que es un malentendido, hay dos puntos a comentar:

**• 1)** `unsigned` es usado en `MySQL` para permitir valores positivos de de 0 hasta 4294967295.

En `MySQL`, siempre que definimos un `UNSIGNED` en cualquier columna significa que no puede usar números negativos, el rango máximo con `INT` `UNSIGNED` es `4294967295`.

Documentación MySQL:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html

Pero en el caso de `SQL Server` si defines tu campo como tipo `INT` este aceptara de forma predeterminada valores desde `-2147483648` hasta `2147483647`, por lo tanto no se tiene que especificar "unsigned" en SQL Server, de hecho esto no existe en `SQL Server`.

Documentación SQL Server:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

**• 2)** En el caso de MySQL se usa `AUTO_INCREMENT` para definir un campo autoincrementable pero en `SQL server` se usa `IDENTITY`

por lo tanto tu script para crear la tabla debería ser:

```
CREATE TABLE departamento (
    id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL    
);
```

Comment: Siempre creí que `unsigned` (sin signo) era para obviar los números negativos y mover el rango del tipo de dato a lo positivo... Pero, dices que es lo contrario? En el enlace a la documentación MySQL que compartes, dice que el máximo `unsigned` es `4294967295`. Tienes cruzada la definición? o yo estoy viendo algo que no es?

Comment: @Arriel  MySQL al usar "UNSIGNED" para un valor tipo INT tendrás valores de 0 a 4294967295 de hecho es lo que indica la documentación, muchas gracias Arriel, veo que escribí lo contrario, lo acabo de modificar.

Comment: Pensaba lo mismo que @Arriel por ello asignaba el unsigned pero me doy cuenta que no es la misma sintaxis que en MySql. Se ve que soy nuevo